# how to save the matplotlib figure by using FigureCanvas within wxagg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, backend

I am using backend AGG to create a canvas that can embed in wx application but I don't know how to save the figure with FigureCanvas, here is the code:

```
import wx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WXAgg") ## switching to wxAgg backend ##
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas   
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
class MPL_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
      wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=-1,pos=(135,70),size=(390,300))
      self.Figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(4, 3))
      self.axes = self.Figure.add_axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.7, 0.7])
      self.FigureCanvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.Figure)
class MyMenu(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
      wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(1100, 500))
      self.MPL = MPL_Panel(self)
      self.Figure = self.MPL.Figure
      self.axes = self.MPL.axes
      self.FigureCanvas = self.MPL.FigureCanvas
    def OnSave(self, event):
      global donnee
      self.Figure.savefig('foo.pdf')


    def Onplota(self):
 #list of x2,y2, because this part doesn't important, I just plot the line and it shows in my interface by using wxpython and matplotlib
    self.axes.plot(x2, y2, '.--')
    self.axes.hold
    self.axes.grid()
    #Render the figure using agg
    self.FigureCanvas.draw()
```

So the probleme is that I want to save the figure using agg, anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't see how that code, as posted, works at all.

Comment: I just pick the part of my code to explain, I didn't put the entire code since my problem concentrates this part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is  nice working code: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx5_sgskip.html